# Accessing the atomic portion of a class in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to access the "atomic" portion of a class in R?

I'm using the package "bit" and I want to access the values of the vector of integers, not only the logical values. How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jens Oehlschlaegel, the maintainer of the package "bit" gave me the answer:
using the `unclass` function, I can access the atomic portion of a class.

I hope this helps.